# Can someone explain what's happening in this code? When I select two columns from different tables the output is always like this

Tags: sql

```
select num1.n, 2 from num1, num2
```

expected output

```
table num1  table num2
2               2
3               3
4               4
5               5
6               6
7
8
9
10
```

actual output

```
num1, num2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   2
7   2
8   2
9   2
10  2
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   2
7   2
8   2
9   2
10  2
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   2
7   2
8   2
9   2
10  2
```

Comment: you are selecting `2`, a constant from num2...

Comment: @Suraj Rao then why the output is like that? the column in table 1 is repeated

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Number "2" is constant in your case.

You need to understand the correct relation between two tables.

After that you can build your select with JOIN to connect data from two tables correctly.

For example:

```
SELECT num1.n, num2.[field_from_table_num2]
FROM num1
JOIN num2 ON num2.[relation_field_or_key]= num1.[relation_field_or_key];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have define static column so that why you receive 2 in second column try following query

```
select num1.n As 'First_Table', num2.n As 'Second_Table'
from num1, num2
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.